# Find $y$ such that $\langle v, y \rangle = \|v\|$

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $v \in \mathbb{R^n}$. Show which vector $y \in \mathbb{R^n}$ satisfies:

$\langle v, y \rangle = \|v\| := \sqrt{ \langle v, v \rangle}$.

Where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the usual inner product.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: For any specific $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, there are infinitely many such vectors.  Are there other properties you're loking for?

Comment: To expand on @NickPeterson's comment: Pick any $\tilde{y}$ with $\langle v, \tilde{y} \rangle \neq 0$. Now look at $y = \frac{\| v \|}{\langle v, \tilde{y} \rangle} \tilde{y}$. What is $\langle v, y \rangle$?

Answer (score 0):

For each $x \not\perp v$ we have $y=\frac{||v||x}{<v,x>}$ satisfies the condition. Now they are the only ones with this property. So, for each direction not ortoghonal to the line spanned by v exists one and only one vector with that property.